# "???" symbols when saving unicode files in C#

Tags: c#, unicode

I'm having some issues, when saving configuration - unicode text is saved as "???". But problem appears only on Windows 2003 with .Net Framework v 2 . When I test my code on WinXP with .Net 4 it works fine, despite it's targeted on .Net Framework v2 in settings.
I tried doing different conversions like

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
      Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, 
                       Encoding.Unicode,
                       Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(backupPathTextBox.Text)));
```

But it always return "???" or some unreadable symbols. I googled this question and found out that all C# strings represented in UTF16 codepage, but there is no UTF16 decoder buitl-in in C#. 
Could anyone guide me to the right direction?

Comment: You mis-interpret what's going on.  Getting a ? is guaranteed when converting to ASCII and the string contains non-ASCII Unicode glyphs.  On any operating system and .net version.

Comment: Ok, then what should I do? Saving text as-is also gives ??

Comment: Don't save as ASCII.  Utf8 is a good choice for text files, the default for StreamWriter.

Comment: That's what I'm doing, and it results as question marks on Windows 2003

Comment: Post actual code that reproduces this problem and doesn't use Encoding.ASCII

Comment: I can't post code since all file operations defined in COM dll, which I use via interop wrapper. But other components using this dll don't have such problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
  Encoding.Convert(Encoding.ASCII, 
                   Encoding.Unicode,
                   Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(backupPathTextBox.Text)));
```

`Encoding.Unicode` is actually the UTF-16LE encoding, where each code unit is stored using two bytes (and so ASCII characters end up with zero bytes between each one). Microsoft call this “Unicode” because it's what they expected to be used as the most common encoding of Unicode back in the very early days, but it didn't work out like that and now the name is completely misleading.

What your code does is:

- converts your text string to UTF-16LE bytes;
- then converts them from ASCII bytes (which they're not) to UTF-16LE bytes, which means an extra zero byte is added between each byte;
- then converts those bytes back to a string as if they were ASCII, which means you'll get basically the same string as you had to begin with, but with three more zero bytes per one character, and non-ASCII characters turned into two.

What exactly were you trying to do with this? If you want to put Unicode string in an ASCII-compatible text file, the encoding you want is generally UTF-8 and never UTF-16. Converting a string to UTF-8 bytes is as simple as:

```
new UTF8Encoding(false).GetBytes(backupPathTextBox.Text)
```

or just use a UTF-8 `TextWriter` to write the string directly.